# (Soft Question) How active an area of research is Non-Commutative Geometry?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, soft-question, noncommutative-algebra, string-theory

I am currently an undergraduate, but I am considering applying for a phd in algebraic geometry or a related field.

I am quite interested in the link between non-commutative geometry and theoretical physics (string theory/QFT).

Speaking to a few of my geometry lecturers and tutors I got the impression, at least from some, that non-commutative geometry and/or it's applications to string theory have died down as areas of research, or that it isn't as "fashionable" as it used to be.

How much truth is there in this?

Comment: None.  There are several non-commutative people in my department.  It all depends on who the professors are.  Just go look up some non-commutative people and figure out what universities they're at.